# How to preserve CORS response headers when throwing exception from a service

Tags: servicestack, cors

I am using ServiceStack to build a RESTful API as a backend to a single-page, ajax heavy app.

I have CORS properly configured and everything works as expected.

Some of my services require authorization and throw exceptions that result in 403 or 401 status codes when the user is not authorized, has a expired token, etc. So far so good.

The problem is that whenever I throw one of these exceptions, ServiceStack doesn't include the CORS headers in the response and then the browser refuses to parse it, as it was an ajax call.

Is there a correct way to throw an exception within a service but preserve the CORS headers?

The work around right now is to not throw the exception, set the headers manually and call response.End(). Just think there might be a better way.

Comment: Are you using ServiceStack v3 or v4?

Comment: I am using the latest v3.9

Comment: Can you post how you are setting up the CORS support?

Comment: Scott, like I said, all the API requests that do not result in exceptions being thrown are being properly handled. The CORS headers are there both on the OPTIONS request and the actual request. The issue is that when I throw an exception, ServiceStack does not keep the CORS headers. I did manage to manually set those headers on non-200 responses and it works (instead of throwing an exception).

Comment: Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());
  SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
 GlobalResponseHeaders = {
 { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
 { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" },
 { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type }
}});